# Send list of Integer[] from ajax to Spring Controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, post, model-view-controller

I' trying to send some data from the frontend to a Controller in Spring. I am able to recover all the data except for the Integer [] objectIds.

This is my ajax function:

```
           var dataToSend = [{ objectIds: 111 }, { objectIds: 222 }];
           dataToSend = JSON.stringify({ 'objectIds': dataToSend });

           $.ajax({
               type:'POST',
               url:'/sendData',
               data:{'start':start, 'end':end, 'locale':locale, dataToSend},
               async:false,
               dataType: "json",
               success:function(data){}
           });
```

And this is my Controller function:

```
    @PostMapping(path="/sendData")
public @ResponseBody String sendData(HttpServletResponse response, 
        @RequestParam(required=true, name="start") String start, 
        @RequestParam(required=true, name="end") String end,
        @RequestParam(required=true, name="locale") Locale locale,
        @RequestParam(required=false, name="objectIds") Integer[] objectIds) throws DocumentException, IOException {

    //some more code
}
```

any idea why it's not working??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in the way you are sending JSON

**Case 1:  How you are sending**

```
 var dataToSend = [{ objectIds: 111 }, { objectIds: 222 }];
dataToSend = JSON.stringify({ 'objectIds': dataToSend });

var mainJSOn = {
    'start': "start",
    'end': "end",
    'locale': "locale",
    dataToSend
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(mainJSOn));
```

OUTPUT:

```
   {"start":"start","end":"end","locale":"locale","dataToSend":"{\"objectIds\":[{\"objectIds\":111},{\"objectIds\":222}]}"}
```

**Case 2: How you should actually send**

```
    var dataToSend1 = [{ objectIds: 111 }, { objectIds: 222 }];
    dataToSend1 = JSON.stringify(dataToSend1 );

    var mainJSOn1 = {
        'start': "start",
        'end': "end",
        'locale': "locale",
        'objectIds': dataToSend1
      }



  console.log(JSON.stringify(mainJSOn1));
```

OUTPUT:

```
{"start":"start","end":"end","locale":"locale","objectIds":"[{\"objectIds\":111},{\"objectIds\":222}]"}
```

Look at the Output of Both Cases.

Change your code like done in Case 2

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/569070/)

Comment: Thanks Ashish Kumar I was definitely forming the json in an erroneous way

Answer (score 0):

Your are stringifying the wrong object and burying the key `objectIds` inside it

Try changing to

```
var dataToSend = JSON.stringify([{objectIds: 111}, {objectIds: 222}]);    

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/sendData',
  data: {
    'start': start,
    'end': end,
    'locale': locale,
    'objectIds': dataToSend
  },
  // async:false,  // NEVER USE THIS!!!!
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {}
});
```